# Where is Emily Wong?

Tags: mass-effect-series

I don't know if you remember the journalist from the two first episodes, **Emily Wong**, the one you can assist in a crime syndicate inquiry if I remind well.
I haven't cross her in my male then female game, so I just wonder if anyone knows where you can find her in Mass Effect 3, if it's even possible to talk to her.

Comment: nvm my earlier comment, I got her mixed up with a certain reporter that I punched... a few times

Comment: You meant the [official punching ball of Commander Shepard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItjuztD300w), aka Khalisah al-Jilani ?? ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Emily_Wong):

> In 2186, Emily Wong reported for FCC News and the Alliance News Network from Earth on the Sol system's mysterious comm buoy outage. She was able to establish off-world communications via a Quantum Entanglement Communicator. While reporting, she witnessed a Reaper descend through Earth's atmosphere into airspace over Los Angeles.
>
> She eventually arrives at El Monte Airport, where she meets some members of the National Guard who are attempting to hold off the Reapers with anti-aircraft guns. The National Guard and their air support lead a counter-attack which is ultimately ineffective.
>
> Wong ponders that the signal she is broadcasting led the Reaper forces to that location. In an attempt to escape in a sky van, Wong is attacked and injured as the Alliance forces and airport are destroyed. Without any weapons left and having lost a lot of blood, she pilots her sky van into the approaching Reaper and her signal is lost.
>
> "Fighter drones closing. Gunships are down. Mom, dad, love you"
>
> "Go on. Make your noise. Try to scare us."
>
> "You want to see how a human dies? At ramming speed"
>
> -Emily Wong's last transmission
>
> As of now she is considered MIA.

Comment: Let's hope she made it, and just broke her radio....

Comment: She died on Twitter. :( Not even ingame... on freaking *Twitter*.

Answer (score 2):

It appears she died in the initial invasion of earth.

http://twitter.com/#!/alliancenewsnet